# set Alignment of a button inside a dockpanel

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to set the HorizontalAlignment of a button to the  the right, but the button will change position. can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong. Thanks everyone in advance.

here is what i have tried so far:

1). `DockPanel.Dock="Right"`

2). `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=CanColorBar}" >
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue"/>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Button x:Name="btnAcceptMerge" Content="Accept Merge"/>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <Run Text=" "/>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Button x:Name="btnCancel"  Content="Cancel Merge" Click="btnCancel_Click"/>
        </InlineUIContainer>
    </TextBlock>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have all your buttons inside the TextBlock. This is not a very optimal or good layout. Try this instead:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="SkyBlue" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=CanColorBar}">
    <Button x:Name="btnAcceptMerge" Content="Accept Merge" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnCancel"  Content="Cancel Merge" Click="btnCancel_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <TextBlock Text=""/>
</DockPanel>
```